# setTracing on Camel with SCALA DSL

Tags: scala, apache-camel

How do I set up tracing  (getContext.setTracing) for all routes when using scala DSL.

I can not see anything on console or logs by doing this:

```
class RouteSendEmailWS extends RouteBuilder {
  getContext.setStreamCaching(true)
  getContext.setTracing(true)

  from("direct:x) ==> { to("mock:onX") }
}
```

Where should I see the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And you are sending data to that route? eg you send data to "direct:x"?. 
If you do not send an data, then there is nothing to trace.

You can read about the tracer here
http://camel.apache.org/tracer

If you want something to happen, you can use a timer instead of "direct:x" as the timer will trigger every second by default.